# High bitrate in AVCONV converted MPG file causes DVD reading problem

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg, linux

I convert AVI to MPEG with folowing command:

```
avconv -i file.avi -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 6000k -c:a mp2 -b:a 384k file.mpg
```

When the MPG file has been burned to DVD it is hard to read afterthat. The DVD on the computer starts to make noise and to read slow the DVD. Also it is hard to watch directly - it is like there is no buffer in the VLC player. The Windows media player doesn't even play the MPG file.

I checked with avprobe the MPG file and another MPG file made with EDIUS program.
Here are the resuts:

MY MPG FILE

```
avprobe my-file.mpg 
avprobe version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:00:59 with gcc 4.6.3
[mpeg @ 0x9b6f240] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, mpeg, from 'my-file.mpg':
  Duration: 00:34:56.47, start: 1.000000, bitrate: 6411 kb/s
    Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
```

EDIUS CREATED MPG FILE

```
avprobe edius.mpg 
avprobe version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:00:59 with gcc 4.6.3
[mpeg @ 0x8449240] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, mpeg, from 'edius.mpg':
  Duration: 00:34:56.47, start: 0.346411, bitrate: 2290 kb/s
    Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 6000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 256 kb/s
```

The two files are with great quality but I am questioning myself how to achieve two things:

What to change in my command line to reach edius bitrate on that line:

```
  Duration: 00:34:56.47, start: 0.346411, bitrate: 2290 kb/s
```

instead of:

```
  Duration: 00:34:56.47, start: 1.000000, bitrate: 6411 kb/s
```

And how to reach this 6000kb in Edius STREAM line:

```
Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 6000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

instead of mine 104857kb :

```
Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

I think that will resolve my problem with burning and reading DVDs.

ALso whe I am converting the yellow sigh appears:

```
[mpeg @ 0x8e75f40] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail
```

Is this a part of the problem?

Thanks in advance!